# set name of properties dynamically JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

```
let myArray=[{id:'name',value:'jan'},{id:'age',value:'19'}];
```

now I want to have a list of myArray just like this :

```
{name:'jan',age:19}
```

i can not do it like this :

```
    let FormValues =[];

  myArray.forEach((x,index)=>{
    
    if(FormValues && FormValues.length===1)
    {
        FormValues[0][x.id]=x.value;
    }
    else
    {
        FormValues.push({x.id:x.value});
    }
    
 })
```

Comment: What is `FormValues` set to? What errors are you getting?

Comment: it's an array, you can see it now

Comment: `FormValues.push({x.id:x.value});` should be `FormValues.push({[x.id]:x.value});`

Comment: yes, that was my answer just use this : [variable]. thanks sir